# Switch case statement printing from the keyboard

Tags: java, branch

I am a beginner, please see the following:

```
public class CaseBreak {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key = 1;
        int dob = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch(dob + key + 1)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("First switch");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Second switch");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Third switch");
            break;    
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Fourth switch");
            break;    
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Fifth switch");
            break;    
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Sixth switch");
            break;    
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Seventh switch");
            break;    
        default:
            System.out.println("Out of Switch! there is no");
        } 
    }
}
```

In the following everything is running fine. But I want to print that number along with the default statement which is invoked when keyboard input goes out of case. Something like ex- number 7 goes to a default and I get "Out of Switch! there is no". I just want that it should also present number after the statement like ( Out of Switch! there is no 7)

Comment: `System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no"+(dob+key+1));`

Answer (score 4):

You can add a string and a number together using `+`, ideally you should store `dob + key + 1` into a variable also so you only calculate it once.

```
int i = dob + key + 1
switch(i)
{
    // ...
    default:
        System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have the number which is `dob + key + 1`. Why don't you print it?

*Note*: it is very important to surround *dob + key +1* with `( )` since `+` is the concatenation operator and you want to tell the compiler to *sum* the numbers.

```
default:
    System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no " + (dob + key + 1));
```

If you write it like this:

```
default:
        System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no " + dob + key + 1);
```

Then you'll get as an output: (Say dob is 1, key is 2)

> Out of Switch!! there is no 121

But if you surround it with parenthesis then you'll get the actual sum of the three integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
default:
System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no"+dob);
```

I think this is what you are looking for. It will tell which number was entered and prints the same along with the statement in sop of default. This is when you want to see the number you have given as input. If you want to see the number on the whole with `+1` which is done in your switch, do `System.out.println("Out of Switch!! there is no"+dob+key+1);`